# python unit test issues mocking pytz getting local time

Tags: python, unit-testing, datetime, mocking, pytz

I am currently trying to write a unit test for this_function

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch, call
from datetime import datetime, timezone, tzinfo

def this_function(utc_current_time):
    cst_time = pytz.timezone("US/Central")
    local_current_time = utc_current_time.astimezone(cst_time)
    return local_current_time
```

my unit test

```
    def test_get_local_time_for_afterhour_check(self, mock_pytz, mock_datetime):
        utc_current_time = datetime(2020, 4, 16, 16, 22, 32, tzinfo=timezone.utc)

        actual = main.get_local_time_afterhour_emr_check(utc_current_time)
        expected = datetime(2020, 4, 16, 11, 22, 32)

        self.assertEqual(actual, expected)
```

the problem i run into is the the date is correct but is the actual also has extra stuff i'm guessing from pytz

```
  datetime(2020, 4, 16, 11, 22, 32,tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Central' CDT-1 day, 19:00:00 DST>
```

i can't figure out how to either mock it out or at min verify the datetime is correct. i tried mocking out pytz but i couldn't get that to work. Also, couldn't figure out how to mock timezone.utc

any help would be great. thanks

Answer (score 0):

to make your value non-timezone aware you can

```
actual = this_function(utc_current_time).replace(tzinfo=None)
```

alternatively you can set the timezone for expected

```
expected = datetime(2020, 4, 16, 11, 22, 32)
cst_time = pytz.timezone("US/Central")
expected = cst_time.localize(expected)
```